# First touch sprite node identification issue

Tags: ios

I am working on simple iOS game. It`s build with Swift 3 and SpriteKit. Idea is that a cannon is placed on the top of the screen and the tip of the cannon rotates 180 degrees. Along the x-axis, the tip points at your finger. The issue is when I make a first touch, the tip of the cannon points around 45 degrees away from my finger. When i move my finger along the x axis, the cannon head rotates around y axis.

This is what I got:
[Thats how it rotates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDEP8.png)

And this is what I need: 
[rotation along x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDVdZ.png)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var cannon:SKSpriteNode!
var touchLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    cannon = self.childNode(withName: "cannon") as! SKSpriteNode
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: self)

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: self)
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    let percent = touchLocation.x / size.width
    let newAngle = percent * 180 - 180
    cannon.zRotation = CGFloat(newAngle) * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0
}
}
```

Above is from GameScene.swift

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Your problem is not clear "the cannon head rotates around y axis" - sprites can only rotate around the z axis, can you explain in a different way what is wrong with the way it rotates?

Comment: Sure. The problem is that when I touch it the first time, the cannon head should face my finger. And when I move my finger along the x axis, the cannon head should follow it

Comment: Here is a clip of what is happening: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By9RPl6gKmtvM01MQ2pNZERRZWM

Comment: OK I see. The zRotation parameter of a sprite is the rotation from its original direction (not its current direction). Your cannon sprite is presumably originally defined facing straight up? So when you touch the left hand side of the screen newAngle becomes zero so you re-rotate your cannon to point straight up (zero degrees from its original direction). When you touch the right hand side of the screen newAngle becomes 180 so you re-rotate your cannon to point straight down.